# How to generate UML diagram for classes using Java existing code?

Tags: java

I have Java project with source code, and I want to get UML diagram for this code automatically. Are there any ways to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Astah](http://astah.net/editions/community) can do this (afaik even in the community version)

Comment: The community version doesn't provide this feature :( Only Astah UML (paid version)